# How to compile kernel modules with debug logs enabled

Tags: linux, logging, kernel, driver, printk

I have downloaded linux kernel source v4.2.0 and built it. Now I am trying to compile one driver module and see the debug logs on console.

I am am compiling the module by following command :

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build M=$PWD
```

also have enabled all the kernel debug logs as below :

```
    #echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk

    sanjeev@sanjeev:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
    8   4   1   7
```

When I load this module can't see kernel logs(having log levels) with dmesg. If I am printing messages with **printk("Some message")**, it is getting printing on the console, but if the same message if I am printing through **printk(KERN_INFO, "Some message")** it is not getting printed on the console. Am I missing any configuration while compiling the module?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was coming because of the comma ',' after log level in the printk
it should be **printk(KERN_INFO "Some message")**